# Get reference of original element after Akka Streams Sink?

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I am trying to use the Amqp alpakka connector as a source and sink.

```
Source<CommittableReadResult, NotUsed> AMQP_SOURCE  
      -> processAndGetResponse 
      -> Sink<ByteString, CompletionStage<Done>> AMQP_SINK
```

I want to acknowledge the message obtained from the Amqp queue, after the Sink's operation is successful. like this:

```
amqp_source(committableReadResult) 
    -> processAndGetResponse 
    -> amqp_sink 
    -> IfSinkOperationSuccess.Then(committableReadResult.ack())
```

How can I achieve this? I basically want to mark the message as acknowledge only after the sink operation is successful.

Comment: If you using akka-stream `v2.5.20+`, I suggest to look at `SourceWithContext` and [Software Mill blog](https://blog.softwaremill.com/painlessly-passing-message-context-through-akka-streams-1615b11efc2c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have a `Sink` which materializes into a `Future[Done]` (Scala API, I believe the Java equivalent is `CompletionStage[Done]`), you can just run a substream with that `Sink` within a `mapAsync` stage.  Data will only pass through when successful.

From a quick perusal of the Alpakka AMQP API, the `Sink`s all materialize that way, so that approach will work.

Assuming that your `doSomethingWithMessage` function results in both the `CommittableReadResult` and a `WriteMessage`, something like the following in Scala will work:

```
def doSomethingWithMessage(in: CommittableReadResult): (CommittableReadResult, WriteMessage) = ???

amqpSource
  .map(doSomethingWithMessage)
  .mapAsync(parallelism) { tup =>
    val (crr, wm) = tup
    val fut = Source.single(crr, wm).runWith(amqpSink)
    fut.flatMap(_ => crr.ack().map(_ => crr.message))
  }.runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is helpful.
In this case, won't the sink be kinda reinitialized a.k.a create a new connection to the amqp server for every element in the stream?